# Jquery datepicker count difference between two dates wont work

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-arithmetic

aim is to count difference from two dates
im still confuse why it wont work, cause i wrote a code from someone's tutorial.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html><body style='background:white;'><head><title>tugas akhir</title>

<meta charset='utf-8'>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/jquery-ui.js'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/jquery.js'>
    <link rel='icon' src='images/lmd.png'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/me.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/datepicker.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.css'>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='tinymce/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>

  <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#arr_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    $( "#dep_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
$('.button').click(function() {
    var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
    $('#ahir').val(days);
});
</script>

<script>
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
</script>
</head>

<p>Choose your dates and hit <em>go</em>.</p>
<input type="text" id="arr_date">
<input type="text" id="dep_date">
    <input type="text" id="hasil">
<button class="button">go</button>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to put the difference date value in id='hasil.
i hope you guys can help my problem. Thank you

Comment: can you show us the link of the tutorial

Comment: In your last edit, you added `$('#akhir').val(days);;`: what is `akhir` item? And remove the second `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation part is ok, you can check with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ryy5p4x/

If you want to set the value in the input having `hasil` as id, as you said by text, simply set like this `$('#hasil').val(days);`

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3ryy5p4x/1/

EDIT: here in your own code, the problem is the structure:

- Your `body` start MUST be after all the `head` section!
- Your link to stylesheets are referencing javascript files, not stylesheet files
- You did not referenced jQUery UI which is containing the datepicker component, but `bootstrap-datepicker`

Correction, using CDN references for the js files (files are on the web, from here: https://code.jquery.com/. If you want to use them locally, copy the content and change the references):

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>tugas akhir</title>

        <!-- Here, the files should be CSS, not JS! -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/jquery-ui.css'>

        <link rel='icon' src='images/lmd.png'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/me.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/datepicker.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.css'>

        <!-- jQuery, here 1.11.1 version, using minified (min) to have a shorter file -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <!-- jQuery UI script, for datepicker -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#arr_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
                $( "#dep_date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            });

            $('.button').click(function() {
                var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
                var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
                var days = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
                $('#hasil').val(days);
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
                alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
            } else {
                alert("jQuery library is not found!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style='background:white;'>
        <p>Choose your dates and hit <em>go</em>.</p>
        <input type="text" id="arr_date" />
        <input type="text" id="dep_date" />
        <input type="text" id="hasil" />
        <button class="button">go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it works. but how if i want to put the value in another textfield like this.

this is my work : http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TCXcX/

Comment: See my fiddle. Your value is stored in the `days` var, so use jQuery to put it where you want: if the destination has the id `sampleId`, use `$('#sampleId').val(days)` for example

Comment: thank you. yes, in jsfiddle it works. but i use jquery 1.11 in my local computer and cant run the same result. can you suggest where i can get jquery plugin that actually works same like in jsfiddle thank you

Comment: This is the basic behaviour of jQuery since the beginning, no problem with your version. Looking back to your head section, you made errors in it, I will update my answer

Comment: See my edit: several problems in your items'order. For the datepicker, I used in the jsfiddle the datepicker of jQuery UI. I think a made a mix between CSS and JS in your initial implementation

Comment: everything works. i've tried to copy and paste your edit in new file and then i ran it. it still cant work when i press button, nothing happen.  It's so different if i run in jsfiddle :(

Comment: There may be problems in the references to your css files, I did not remove them but you can comment. And use the console of your navigator to see if there is any error. Basically, if you want I can edit and give you the minimal items to work, then you complete